# ReactJs Webpack make errors every time

Tags: reactjs, webpack

template.[image]

[My React-Redux Project](https://github.com/vladimirpetukhov/IncredibleWeb/tree/main/frontend)

I learn about webpack and babel and it is very difficult for me to configure webpack for existing project.I can't find the most usseful solution about it.Is there anywhera a full list of loaders and packages where I need to install to  be sure that I have all of them or some webpack.config full

Comment: Please post text rather than images of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webpack isn't causing this error. The fact that you're declaring the state outside of the class component's constructor is. You can see an example of state in the old class component style [in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class).

Comment: Ok but this is in the reducer actions

Comment: The error in your screenshot is from [this line](https://github.com/vladimirpetukhov/IncredibleWeb/blob/278da91aeb1f1772ebc3eb10e3c654d92336a98e/frontend/src/components/MovieInfo.js#L9).